# How can I get text of an element in Selenium WebDriver, without including child element text?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Consider:

```html
<div id="a">This is some
   <div id="b">text</div>
</div>
```

Getting "This is some" is nontrivial.  For instance, this returns "This is some text":

```
driver.find_element_by_id('a').text
```

How does one, in a general way, get the text of a specific element without including the text of its children?

Comment: So for the record what I ended up doing was doing it in javascript... I have jQuery on the pages I'm testing, so I took advantage of the fact that Selenium automatically converts dom elements returned from javascript into WebElements:  my_result = driver.execute_script('return [...call to my jquery function..]')

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's a general solution:

```
def get_text_excluding_children(driver, element):
    return driver.execute_script("""
    return jQuery(arguments[0]).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
    }).text();
    """, element)
```

The element passed to the function can be something obtained from the `find_element...()` methods (i.e., it can be a `WebElement` object).

Or if you don't have jQuery or don't want to use it, you can replace the body of the function above with this:

```
return self.driver.execute_script("""
var parent = arguments[0];
var child = parent.firstChild;
var ret = "";
while(child) {
    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
        ret += child.textContent;
    child = child.nextSibling;
}
return ret;
""", element)
```

I'm actually using this code in a test suite.

Comment: right, what I basically realized is... don't use selenium's search methods, just use jquery

Comment: @josh, I would disagree with that... Seleniums methods are meant to mock interactions from a user's POV whereas jQuery is not. Yes you can use both to grab elements but in general there should be relatively few situations where you'd need to execute javascript.

Comment: The first code snippet assumes jQuery is loaded in the page. The 2nd code snippet works whether or not jQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 15):

In the HTML which you have shared:

```html
<div id="a">This is some
   <div id="b">text</div>
</div>
```

The text `This is some` is within a [text node](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp). To depict the [text node](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createtextnode) in a structured way:

```html
<div id="a">
    This is some
   <div id="b">text</div>
</div>
```

---

### This use case

To extract and print the text **`This is some`** from the *text node* [using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [python](/questions/tagged/python) client, you have two ways as follows:

- Using `splitlines()`: You can identify the parent element i.e. `<div id="a">`, extract the `innerHTML` and then use `splitlines()` as follows:
- using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[0])
  ```
- using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#a").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[0])
  ```
- Using `execute_script()`:  You can also use the [`execute_script()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method which can synchronously execute JavaScript in the current window/frame as follows:
- using *xpath* and *firstChild*:

  ```
  parent_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']")
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', parent_element).strip())
  ```
- using *xpath* and *childNodes[n]*:

  ```
  parent_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']")
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[1].textContent;', parent_element).strip())
  ```

Comment: The second "using xpath" is followed by "find_element_by_css_selector".

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
def get_true_text(tag):
    children = tag.find_elements_by_xpath('*')
    original_text = tag.text
    for child in children:
        original_text = original_text.replace(child.text, '', 1)
    return original_text
```

Comment: this runs disgustingly slowly, though... there has to be a better way??

Comment: You should always try to get the most specific child element you can. In this case, if you've got a lot of children elements it'll run slow.  Why don't you check if the element actually has text before returning, i.e make the XPath: `*[string-length(text()) > 1]` or make the for loop check for `child.text` being not null and not empty. Also, what about CSS selector? XPath queries are very slow anyway, so maybe a CSS selector will be faster.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do a replace. You can get the length of the children text, subtract that from the overall length, and slice into the original text.  That should be substantially faster.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Selenium was only built to work with [Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), not [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) nodes.

If you try to use a function like `get_element_by_xpath` to target the text nodes, Selenium will throw an `InvalidSelectorException`.

One workaround is to grab the relevant HTML with Selenium and then use an HTML parsing library like [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)) that can handle text nodes more elegantly.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

inner_html = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#a')[0].get_attribute("innerHTML")
inner_soup = BeautifulSoup(inner_html, 'html.parser')

outer_html = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#a')[0].get_attribute("outerHTML")
outer_soup = BeautifulSoup(outer_html, 'html.parser')
```

From there, there are several ways to search for the Text content. You'll have to experiment to see what works best for your use case.

Here's a simple one-liner that may be sufficient:

```
inner_soup.find(text=True)
```

If that doesn't work, then you can loop through the element's child nodes with .contents() and check their object type.

Beautiful Soup has [four types of elements](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-objects), and the one that you'll be interested in is the [NavigableString](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) type, which is produced by Text nodes. By contrast, Elements will have a type of [Tag](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag).

```
contents = inner_soup.contents

for bs4_object in contents:

    if (type(bs4_object) == bs4.Tag):
        print("This object is an Element.")

    elif (type(bs4_object) == bs4.NavigableString):
        print("This object is a Text node.")
```

Note that Beautiful Soup doesn't support XPath expressions. If you need those, then you can use some of the workarounds [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup).