# What's the best way to select this kind of text in HTML?

Tags: html, xpath, css-selectors

```
<td>
some text here
<a href="http://blablabla">ch1</a>
</td>
```

What is the best way to select `some text here`? I want to do this with css selectors or xpath, and better **without** jquery. Thank you. (I know this question is very likely to be a duplicate...)

Comment: what you want is ***the first*** text node, so just use `text()[1]` to access it, `text()` works in this case but it's not safe I think (because there may be some other text nodes added in future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the `text()` of the node:

```
//td/text()
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint index.html --html --xpath '//td/text()'
some text here
```

---

Also, to follow @King King's comment, you may want to explicitly get the first text node by specifying an index (would help in case there are other `td`'s text child nodes):

```
//td/text()[1]
```

Though, `//td/text()` works perfectly on the input you've provided.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but it seems `text()` can't be used in selenium xpath selector.

Comment: @laike9m yeah, what you can do is to follow the advice suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12397642/771848) and "subtract" link text from the `td`'s text.

Comment: @laike9m alternatively, you can get the `innerHTML` of the `td` and use an HTML Parser (like `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` in case of Python) to extract the desired text.

Comment: Thank you alecxe, I tried calling `.text` on the `td` webelement and got the text I want.