# Python and how to get text from a Selenium element WebElement object

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the tag text content on an HTML page by using Selenium methods, but it seems method `someElement.getText()` is not available in Python.
Is there a way?

Here's a traceback:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325454/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-via-the-python-api-without

Comment: It is about replacing text with JavaScript execution.

Comment: I was pointing at the .text method cited inside the question

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Once you locate the element you can use the text property.

Example:

```
for element in self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img'):
       print element.text
       print element.tag_name
       print element.parent
       print element.location
       print element.size
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I found `element.get_attribute('text')` works too and it with more possibilities.

Comment: You need to be careful if the text is hidden, e.g. via CSS, on the page. In that case you need to do element.get_attribute("innerText"). See: http://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: This reply even tough expanding on a different subject finally clarified the different objects returned by find_element and find_elements (with the plural s) :

Comment: The `.text` property (or any of the others) weirdly was not showing up in code completion. However, it did work perfectly when I used it! The same with @Alex's `get_attribute('text')`. Awesome info!

Answer (score 7):

Selenium get text from an element (just add ".text"):

1. For all elements of the list

   ```
    tree = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(<the_XPATH>)
    for i in tree:
        print(i.text)
   ```
2. [ ] fetchby number

   ```
    tree = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(<the_XPATH>)
    print(tree[0].text)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was in a task to extract text between the target tags, but the *x.text* method didn't work for me. This is because some text are saved as invisible elements. For invisible elements, use:

```
list1 = [x.get_attribute("innertext") for x in driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually with Python 3 this worked for me:

```
obj = browser.find_element_by_xpath("the_XPATH")
print(obj.text)
```

Is not necessary iterate the element because launch a Traceback:

```
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```