# Can't figure out how to scrape page w/ selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I know how to get to the page of results I want to scrape via selenium, but I can't figure out how to actually scrape the page of results. I've tried with mechanize, too, but that didn't get me much further. Here's where I am now:

```
import re
import urllib2
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import datetime
import time
import smtplib
import atexit
import signal
import json
import os
import gspread
import sys
import gc

script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/usr/bin/phantomjs", service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])

#launches headless browser, completes proper search in Casenet
def main():

    driver.get('https://www.courts.mo.gov/casenet/cases/nameSearch.do')

    if 'Service Unavailable' in driver.page_source:
        log('Casenet website seems to be down. Receiving "service unavailable"')
        driver.quit()
        gc.collect()
        return False

    court = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('courtId'))

    court.select_by_visible_text('All Participating Courts')

    case_enter = driver.find_element_by_id('inputVO.lastName')

    case_enter.send_keys('Wakefield & Associates')

    driver.find_element_by_id('findButton').click()

    time.sleep(1)

    number_of_pages = 204

    for i in range(number_of_pages):

        output_trs = []

        party = (driver.find_element_by_class_name('outerTable'))

        output_trs.append(party)

        print output_trs

main()
```

Eventually the idea is to store the parties, case numbers and filing dates as strings in a .csv. When I print output_trs now, I get:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c4e7b9e0-7a3b-11e8-83f2-b9030062270d", element=":wdc:1530125781332")
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to print the web element object [rather than its text content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022764/python-and-how-to-get-text-from-selenium-element-webelement-object/28022996).

one way to print the text content (beware of encoding):

```
for content in output_trs:
    print content.text
```