# How to use storetext command in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to save a text, as a variable, from a website with python.

`driver.find_element_by_class_name('plaint').storetext()`

I don't know how to do this right.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python and how to get text from Selenium element WebElement object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022764/python-and-how-to-get-text-from-selenium-element-webelement-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using selenium to store the text why not try just grabbing the information and storing it into your own variable.

```
element_to_store = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class name").text()
```

Lets say you use class name and `.text()` to find an element and its text value. once you use `element_to_store` to find the text, you can then use `element_to_store` and call it when you need it as its value is the `.text()` string of the element you searched for.