# Python not returning the text from the H3 tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The structure that I am looking at is the following

```
<div id="historyContainer">
    <div class id="offerHistory">
        <div class="theTitle">…</div>
        <br>
        <p>…</p>
        <br>
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Python

```
offerHistory = browser.find_element_by_id('offerHistory')
title = offerHistory.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
print(title)
```

This is what prints

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d7aef4eab17ec32e0280c1177b5016d9", element="eaf8e28e-9620-4e94-81a8-f7e13edc2c48")>]
```

How do I print 'Title'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python and how to get text from Selenium element WebElement object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022764/python-and-how-to-get-text-from-selenium-element-webelement-object)

Comment: The return value is a list, so if you only want the first one (because you know you only have one): `print(title[0].text)` should work

Comment: @chatterone I get a index out of bounds

Comment: If you get index out of bounds, then that output is not what you get, because it shows a list `[<selenium...>]`

Answer (score 0):

Add ".text":

```
title = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
print(title.text)
```

Comment: I get an error when I do that. Attribute Error, list object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Not ideal as the h3 is in this specific block.

Comment: If I understand correctly `find_elements_by_tag_name` returns a list. In order for this code to work, you either have to iterate over `title` or use a dict comprehension.  

`print([t.text for t in title])`

Comment: @denys.halenok this prints out [u'Hello World']. If I do t.text[0], it will print out [u'H']. How can I have it just print Hello World?

Comment: @soldfor
Try this:
`for t in title: print(t.text)`

Comment: `title[0].text` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Within the `<div class id="offerHistory">` parent node:

```
<div class id="offerHistory">
    <div class="theTitle">…</div>
    <br>
    <p>…</p>
    <br>
    <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

There is only one `<h3>` tag which is correctly returned by:

```
title = offerHistory.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
```

So when you `print(title)` the element is printed as:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d7aef4eab17ec32e0280c1177b5016d9", element="eaf8e28e-9620-4e94-81a8-f7e13edc2c48")>]
```

---

In your usecase you are looking to extract the text **Title** from the `<h3>` node and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#offerHistory h3").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='offerHistory']//h3").text)
  ```