# How to get text from parent element and exclude text from children (C# Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to get the text only from a parent element and not its children in Selenium?

Example:
Suppose I have the following code:

```html
<div class="linksSection>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" id="google">Google Link
    <span class="helpText">This link will take you to Google's home page.</span>
  </a>
  ...
</div>
```

In C# (or whatever language), I will have:

```
string linktext = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".linksSection > a#google")).Text;
Assert.AreEqual(linkText, "Google Link", "Google Link fails text test.");
```

However, the linktext will have "Google LinkThis link will take you to Google's home page."

Without doing a bunch of string manipulation (such as getting the text of all the children and subtracting that from resultant text of the parent), is there a way to get just the text from a parent element?

Comment: Simple answer is: no, you have to do the string manipulation. A more involved answer would be a combination of JavaScript and XPath substring-before() method. http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_2.html#Functions~substring-before But that is still string manipulation, just at a different level.

Comment: Thanks!  My current solution is to do a simple "string.Contains()" verification. But that may be error prone in some situations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get text of an element in Selenium WebDriver (via the Python api) without including child element text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325454/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-via-the-python-api-without)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a [common problem](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5459) in `selenium` since you cannot directly access text nodes - in other words, your XPath expressions and CSS selectors have to point to an actual element.

Here is the list of possible solutions for your problem:

- get the parent element's text, for each child, get the text and remove it from the parent's text. What you would have left is the desired text - `Google Link` in your case.
- if you want to get the `Google Link` just to make an assertion, it could be that you would be okay with checking if the parent's text s*tarts with* `Google Link`. See [`StringAssert.StartsWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243970.aspx).
- get the `outerHTML` of the parent's text and feed to an HTML Parser, like [`Html Agility Pack`](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). Something along these lines:

  ```
  string outerHTML = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".linksSection > a#google")).GetAttribute("outerHTML");

  HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
  html.LoadHtml(outerHTML);

  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode a = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@id='google']");
  HtmlNode text = strong.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::text()");

  Console.WriteLine(text.InnerText.Trim());
  ```

Comment: How can we do it in Selenium Java? I'm trying to find it out, but couldn't find LoadHtml function there... can anyone help me here?

Comment: @zeal LoadHtml is part of Html Agility Pack, which is only available for C# as far as I am aware.

Comment: @alecxe Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, you saved me a ton of time! I also noticed that HtmlAgilityPack has GetDirectInnerText method which does the trick.

Comment: AgilityPack only works if the source code is complete, like any web scrapper (ex: beautifulsoup) it does not work if the source code is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

there is three ways to do the job.

1. replace the unwanted text from child node with '''', the logic is just like the other answers.
2. use js :

```
    private static String OWN_TEXT_JS = "arr=[];content=document.querySelector(arguments[0]);for(i=0,len=content.childNodes.length;i<len;i++){if(content.childNodes[i].nodeType===3){arr.push(content.childNodes[i].nodeValue);}}str=arr.join(\"\"); return str;";
    Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor) WebDriver).executeScript(OWN_TEXT_JS, path);
    if (!(result instanceof String))
       return null;
    else 
       return (String) result;
```

3. use html parser, in java it's jsoup.

```
    element= webDriver.findElement...
    String result = Jsoup.parse(element.getAttribute("outerHTML")).selectFirst(element.getTagName()).ownText();
```

```
    WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html"));
    Jsoup.parse(webElement.getAttribute("outerHTML")).selectFirst(csspath).ownText();
```