# How to get dynamic body text in Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium

I need to get text value as indicated below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <b>Some Text I can find using xPath</b>
            <hr>
            **TEXT I WOULD LIKE TO FIND THAT IS BEING ADDED DYNAMICALLY - it will be different number every time page loads**
            <hr>
            **some other text dynamically added**
        </body>
    </html>
```

I tried by using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/text()[1]"));
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's not straight forward due to the WebDriver not handling anything but element nodes. I opened a while ago two issues: one against the [WebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2840) and another one against the [W3C WebDriver specification](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/340). (vote for them if, it helps showing a need of the user base).

Meanwhile, as a (painful) workaround, you will need to rely on `JavascriptExecutor` capabilities of your `WebDriver`. An example (in another context, thus will have to be adapted to your specifics), in [one of my older answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741076/how-to-use-selenium-get-text-from-an-element-not-including-its-sub-element/39741461#39741461).

Adapted to your case, with the note *it may contain bugs cause by typos* (I haven't checked it):

```
WebElement contextNode=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body"));
if(driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
  String jswalker=
      "var tw = document.createTreeWalker("
     +   "arguments[0],"
     +   "NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,"
     +   "{ acceptNode: function(node) { return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;} },"
     +    "false"
     + ");"
     + "var ret=null;"
     // skip over the number of text nodes indicated by the arguments[1]
     + "var skip;"
     + "for(skip=0; tw.nextNode() && skip<arguments[1]; skip++);"
     + "if(skip==arguments[1]) { " // found before tw.nextNode() ran out
     +   "ret=tw.currentNode.wholeText.trim();"
     + "}"
     + "return ret;"
  ;
  int textNodeIndex=3; // there will be empty text nodes before after <b>
  Object val=((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    jswalker, contextNode, textNodeIndex
  );
  String textThatINeed=(null!=val ? val.toString() : null);
}
```

Please let me know if/how it works.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Closest to a solution for me is using

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the closest I got to a solution is this for me: value = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
value.getText().split("\n")[2]; - since dynamic value I need always apper on the same line in page (in my case third one). Thanks though, if no one presentes something more elegant I will use this one.