# Selenium - How to retrieve text from a child (text) node among multiple child nodes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My HTML looks like :

```
<div id="cc" class="col-md-6" _ngcontent-c12="">
  <h5 _ngcontent-c12="">Blah Blah</h5>
  My Answer
</div>
```

When I use :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("cc")).getText()
```

It returns me "Blah Blah My Answer"

I need only "My Answer" to be returned. Is there a way to do that through Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use selenium get Text from an element not including it's sub-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741076/how-to-use-selenium-get-text-from-an-element-not-including-its-sub-element)

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have provided to retrieve the text **My Answer** you can use the following code block :

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("cc"));
String mytext = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;", elem);
```