# How to extract the error message 'Incorrect username or password' on github login page

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get XPATH for an error message on github login page.(https://github.com/login).
But I can't get XPATH for this element in chrome

I put incorrect credential and saw 'Incorrect username or password'
After that:

1. I tried to copy XPATH by chrome `$x("//*[@id='js-flash-container']/div/div/text()")` but it returned (2) [text, text]
2. `$x("//div[contains(text(), 'Incorrect username or password.')]")` but it returned nothing

HTML:

```
<div class="flash flash-full flash-error">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="flash-close js-flash-close" type="button" aria-label="Dismiss this message">
      <svg class="octicon octicon-x" viewBox="0 0 12 16" version="1.1" width="12" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.48 8l3.75 3.75-1.48 1.48L6 9.48l-3.75 3.75-1.48-1.48L4.52 8 .77 4.25l1.48-1.48L6 6.52l3.75-3.75 1.48 1.48L7.48 8z"></path></svg>
    </button>

      Incorrect username or password.

  </div>
</div>
```

I need an error message. But I haven't

```
private By error = By.xpath("//*[@id='js-flash-container']/div/div/text()");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to use `cssSelector`...

```
String error = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div .flash")).getText().trim();
System.out.println(error);
```

But if you want XPATH use:

```
String error = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div[@class="container"]')).getText().trim();
System.out.println(error);
```

Comment: Don't forget a `.trim()`... that whitespace is a mess.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for pointing that out! I also learned a lot from your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39752671/8179099)

Answer (score 1):

To extract the error message **Incorrect username or password.** on github login page `https://github.com/login` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#js-flash-container div.container"))).getText());
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='js-flash-container']//div[@class='container']"))).getText());
  ```

Comment: Since the ID is unique on the page, you can remove the `div` from the first part locators, e.g. CSS selector would be `#js-flash-container div.container`.

Comment: Actually... since there's a ton of whitespace before and after the desired text even when specifying the `div.container`, you might as well just use the ID alone, `js-flash-container`, and `.trim()`... since you're going to have to trim anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox I've located that element and found the xpath to be:

**/html/body/div[3]/main/div/form/div[2]/div/div**

I loaded up firefox selenium and found this element by xpath:

**WebElement error_msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath( ELEMENT_XPATH ));**

Then to get text I use:

**Text error_msg_str = error_msg.getText();**

You could then compare this string with "Incorrect username or password." , and if these match you **raise** an error.