# How to get text thats lying direcly under the div using selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

This is sort of how looks (See below).I want to save the text "Page 1 to 20" in a string variable for later use.

This is what I did: `string numOfPages = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='tabletransaction']/text()")).Text;`

i´ve tried in multiple ways but as the result is an [Object Text] it don´t work as it needs to be an element.

```
<div id="tabletransaction">
    <table id ="ticketransaction">
        <thead><tr><th>Some text</th></tr></thead>
        <thead><tr><th>Some text</th></tr></thead>
        <thead><tr><th>Some text</th></tr></thead>
        <thead><tr><th>Some text</th></tr></thead>
    </table>

    Page 1 to 20
</div>
```

Comment: maybe text is not an element and it cannot be an element? element here is a `div` which contains text

Comment: I know that, but how can i fetch the text. If i try to do that direclty on the div tag all the text including all the <thead> text are retrived

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text from parent element and exclude text from children (C# Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945692/how-to-get-text-from-parent-element-and-exclude-text-from-children-c-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `/text()` from your XPath:

> Your xpath doesn't return an element; it returns a text node. While this might have
>   been perfectly acceptable in Selenium RC (and by extension, Selenium IDE), the methods
>   on the WebDriver WebElement interface require an element object, not just any DOM node
>   object. WebDriver is working as intended. To fix the issue, you'd need to change the
>   HTML markup to wrap the text node inside an element, like a `<span>`.

Reference: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5459#issuecomment-192110781

NOTE: Unfortunately, if you remove `/text()` from the XPath, you will now be selecting the text of the entire element. Without any selectors wrapped around the `"Page 1 to 20"` text, it is not possible to just "select" this text.

---

Here's a naive way to solve your specific problem:

Select the `<div>`.`Text` and the `<table>`.`Text`, then subtract (`string.Replace`) the `<table>`.`Text` from the `<div>`.`Text`:

```
// "Some text\r\nSome text\r\nSome text\r\nSome text\r\nPage 1 to 20"
string divText = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("tabletransaction")).Text;

// ""Some text\r\nSome text\r\nSome text\r\nSome text"
string tableText = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ticketransaction")).Text;

// "Page 1 to 20"
string remainingText = divText.Replace(tableText, string.Empty).Trim();
```