# Get text from header besides some attribute

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

HTML

```
<span [@class="some class"]> 
    <h1> Some text 
        <a> another text </a> 
    </h1>
</span>
```

How can I write an XPath to get the text under `h1` that doesn't contain the text inside the child `a`?

Comment: Can you update what exactly you mean by "h1" `besides` "a"?

Comment: @Kate I edited the question to clarify what I think the question is. Please adjust if my assumption is not correct. If my assumption *is* correct, you can't do this. Any attempt to pull text from the `h1` will get the text in the `a` also. One thing you can do is pull the text from `h1` and then remove text from contained elements, e.g. the `a`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text from parent element and exclude text from children (C# Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945692/how-to-get-text-from-parent-element-and-exclude-text-from-children-c-selenium)

Comment: Sorry, I mean get only "h1" and remove "a" from this text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below XPath :-

```
//h1[not(self::a)]
```

OR

```
//span[@class='some class']//h1[not(self::a)]
```

Above XPath select everything excluding a tag

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score -1):

The xpath for "Some text" is `/h1/text()` -- you need  type text node.