# Access specific text in body that has no tag

Tags: dom, selenium, xpath

This the DOM of page,

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="Content">
        Take/O a/O look/O at/O the/O section/O about/O filling/O in/O forms/O   using/O
        <div id="Footer">
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to access text that is not under any tag just body after `<div id="Content">` and before `<div id="Footer">` in page body.

I tried:

1. `drv.findElement(( By.xpath("//html/body"))).getText();` but this will give me full text in page under body tag.
2. `drv.findElement(( By.xpath("//html/body/data")))` // error Unable to locate element

now can I use following preceding xpath option, as I doubt that this will also look for tag in page?

Comment: in the html all the nodes is niot closed. so your text now in `//html/head/body/div`

Answer (score 1):

From your wording, I assume that you actually mean to say that this is your html code, with closed head and div tags:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="Content"></div>
        Take/O a/O look/O at/O the/O section/O about/O filling/O in/O forms/O   using/O
        <div id="Footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In that case, the answer of this question, is what you are looking for: [How to get text of an element in Selenium WebDriver (via the Python api) without including child element text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325454/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-via-the-python-api-without)

Comment: I was in doubt if I should have flagged this as a duplicate, but since the other question is specific to python, I chose not to. Even if the answer I linked to is in no way python-specific.

Comment: Yes @KjetilNordin, but I am not able to inject java script - jQuery over publicly hosted service [link](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process) pls try it and suggest how to get text after processing.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crude solution using Java Strings.

```
// get the page source 
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();

// split the pafe source into 2. temp[0] will contain the page source
// before <div id="Content"> and temp[1] will contain page source after 
String[] temp1 = pageSource.split("<div id=\"Content\">");

// get the required text by splitting the temp1[1]
String[] temp2 = temp1[1].split("<div id=\"Footer\">");

// required text will be contained in the temp2[0]
String requiredText = temp2[0];
```

This solution is not complete. I cannot provide the accurate code without seeing your entire DOM. But I think you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks @lost your solution worked, but still looking for perfect solution to the problem.

Comment: @SDV, I am not sure there is any direct solution in Selenium which can handle your issue as your scenario is unique.