# How to read a untag value using selenium xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

If i try to read the text "Total Number = 533" using the following xpath
//*[@id='Content']
it returns the value along with the content in the table tag also. but i just want to read the text "Total Number = 533" alone.

```
<div id="Content">
<h1>Suspended Accounts Report</h1>
Total Number = 533
<br>
<table>
<thead>
...........
<tbody>
..............
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text of an element in Selenium WebDriver (via the Python api) without including child element text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325454/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-via-the-python-api-without)

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath

```
//div[@id='Content']/text()[2]
```

Try this to select 2nd Div

```
//div[2][@id='Content']/text()[2]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: From the OP's example, "Total Number = 533" seems to be the 1st child text node of `div[@id='Content']`, not 2nd

Comment: If you see the HTML then you will find that div tag is not closed so it will take Suspended Accounts Report so expected result is in 2nd node

Comment: I get the following error when i run it on the code:org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //[@id='Content']/text() is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@id='Content']/text() because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: you are using  //[@id='Content']/text() while I have give xpath with //div[@id='Content']/text()[2] .. try it please