# How to get value between parent and child node using xpath?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to extract vale between parent and child node using Xpath. How to achieve that?

```
**<div class="Shareaccess">
    Value to be extract
       <a href="javascript:shareAccessValue()" id="shareKey">
             KEY
       </a>
       <span></span>
  </div>**
```

How to get text value output as '**Value to be extract**'?
It should not be '**Value to be extract KEY**'.
'**KEY**' should be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the child text from the result

> Java syntax

```
String allText = driver.findElement(By.className("Shareaccess")).getText();
String childText = driver.findElement(By.id("shareKey")).getText();
String parentText = allText.replace(childText, "");
```

`parentText` will be "Value to be extract"

Comment: But is it possible to create single xpath which will ignore child text from the result without using java functions? Only xpath should ignore the contents.

Comment: @SanketChandak No, selenium doesn't support it currently. Another option is to use [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19040341/5168011)

Comment: @SanketChandak What do you mean? Selenium API doesn't support it, there isn't really much more information I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**C#:**

```
string parentText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='shareKey']/parent::div").Text().Replace(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='shareKey']").Text(),"");
```

Comment: yes, saw it coming so i changed the code try the new one its like in the other example but in one line and less variable to define.