# Selenium Python, extract text from node and ALL child nodes

Tags: selenium, python-3.6

I have the opposite problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238364/python-and-selenium-get-text-excluding-child-nodes-text). I can't get the text more than one layer deep.

HTML is structured in the following manner:

```
    <span class="data">
        <p>This text is extracted just fine.</p>
        <p>And so is this.</p>
        <p>
            And this.
            <div>
                <p>But this text is not extracted.</p>
            </div>
        </p>
        <div>
            <p>And neither is this.</p>
        </div>
    </span>
```

My Python code looks something like this:

```py
    el.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'data')]").text
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of relying on [WebElement.text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) property consider querying [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property
2. Consider using [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as it will make your test more robust and reliable in case if the element you're looking for is loaded by i.e. [AJAX](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium) call

Assuming all above:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='data']"))).get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the same with child elements:

```
print(el.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'data')]").text)
print(el.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'data')]/div").text)
print(el.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'data')]/p").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the referred `el` in your original post. But able to get all the text using the below.

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='data']").text
```

**Output:**

> 'This text is extracted just fine.\nAnd so is this.\nAnd this.\nBut this text is not extracted.\nAnd neither is this.'