# How to get span's text without inner attribute's text with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
<span class="cname">
    <em class="multiple">2017</em> Ford 
</span>
<span class="cname">
     Toyota
</span>
```

I want to get only "FORD" and TOYOTA in span.

```
test.find_element_by_class_name('cname').text
```

return "**2017** FORD" and "TOYOTA". So how can i get particular text of span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure XPath solution:

```
//span[@class='cname']//text()[not(parent::em[@class='multiple'])]
```

And if you alse want to filter white-space-only text-nodes():

```
//span[@class='cname']//text()[not(parent::em[@class='multiple']) and not(normalize-space()='')]
```

Both return text-nodes not an element. So Selenium will probably fail.
Take a look here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/33097 on how to get a text-node().
Otherwise use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67518169/3710053

**EDIT:**

Another way to go is this XPath:

```
//span[@class='cname']
```

And then use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45238811/3710053) python-example to get only direct text()-nodes.

**EDIT 2**

```
all_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='cname']").text
child_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='cname']/em[@class='multiple']").text

parent_text = all_text.replace(child_text, '')
```

Comment: for second one it says "it is an onject, it must be an element" what do i need to do?

Comment: I suppose Selenium expects an element not a text-node. So this pure XPath solution will not work. ;-(

Comment: can you type it again without //text()?

Comment: That wil not give the wanted result. I will add an extra option to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent element text without the child element text as following:

```
total_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(parent_div_element_xpath).text
child_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(child_div_element_xpath).text

parent_only_text = total_text.replace(child_text, '')
```

So in your specific case try the following:

```
total_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='cname']").text
child_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@class='multiple']).text

parent_only_text = total_text.replace(child_text, '')
```

Or to be more precise

```
father = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='cname']")
total_text  = father.text
child_text = father.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='multiple']").text
parent_only_text = total_text.replace(child_text, '')
```

In a general case you can define and use the following method:

```
def get_text_excluding_children(driver, element):
    return driver.execute_script("""
    return jQuery(arguments[0]).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
    }).text();
    """, element)
```

The `element` argument passed here is the webelement returned by `driver.find_element`
In your particular case you can find the element with:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='cname']")
```

and then pass it to `get_text_excluding_children` and it will return you the required text

Comment: when there is a span without "multiple" class, code can not find child text and give error. how can i deal with it ?

Comment: Depends what that span has. In case it contains known text you can use "//span[contains(text(),'The known span text')]".   xpath can be built exactly based on what information you have about the element(s), their parents and children

Comment: i changed my code in question can you check it?

Comment: I updated the answer with universal method that retrieves the text from the parent element only using JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

If can have a check for integer, if it is a integer then don't print or do something else otherwise print them for `//span[@class='cname'`

**Code :**

```
cname_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='cname']")
for cname in cname_list:
    if cname.text.isdigit() == True:
        print("It is an integer")
    else:
        print(cname.text)
```

or

```
cname_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='cname']")
for cname in cname_list:
    if type(cname.text) is int:
        print("We don't like int for this use case") # if you don't want you can simply remove this line
    else:
        print(cname.text)
```

Comment: it says "'WebElement' object has no attribute 'execute_script'"

Comment: I have given you two ways, may one of them would help you. check it out and let me know