# How to use "not" attribute with "class name" in Xpath?

Tags: python, xpath

```
//span[@class='cname']//text()[not(parent::em[@class='multiple']) and not(normalize-space()='')]
```

I need to remove `text()` in this code. Because when I use `text()` it becomes an object. But if I type "`.text`" at the end of my python code it turns to element.

I need an element not an object. So I need to rewrite "`text()`" from the code without any other changes, or change it from object to element.

Comment: An python example om how to get only the direct-text()-nodes of een element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45238811/3710053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the parent element of that `text()` you could just add `/..` or `/parent::*` to the end of the XPath

```
//span[@class='cname']//text()[not(parent::em[@class='multiple']) and not(normalize-space()='')]/..
```

or

```
//span[@class='cname']//text()[not(parent::em[@class='multiple']) and not(normalize-space()='')]/parent::*
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67518131/11722451 can you help me