# Filter extracted text by html tag with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have to work with an html structure that looks like this:

```
<div class='divClass'>
    <h5>Article 1</h5>
    <p>Paragraph one written in 2022</p>
    <p>(1) This <sup>1</sup>paragraph <sup>2</sup>has footnotes.</p>
    <p>This paragraph has a different <a class='footnotelink'>3</a>footnote.</p>
</div>
```

I need to extract the text from this div, but the footnotes  have to be filtered out.

Here are some more details about the structure:

- There can be 0 or many `<p>` tags
- Each `<p>` tag may or may not contain footnotes of any type
- Each `<p>` tag can contain desirable numbers that should not be removed
- The `<h5>` can be replaced by `<h4>`
- Footnotes can be in `<sup>` tags or in `<a>` tags with class `'footnotelink'`

If I use `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'divClass').text` I receive the unfiltered version which looks like this:

```
Article 1\nParagraph one written in 2022\n(1) This 1paragraph 2has footnotes.\nThis paragraph has a different 3footnote.
```

What I need is this:

```
Article 1\nParagraph one written in 2022\n(1) This paragraph has footnotes.\nThis paragraph has a different footnote.
```

I can't simply filter out numbers because they may appear in the text outside of a footnote.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238364/python-and-selenium-get-text-excluding-child-nodes-text) is similar but filters out text of all text nodes instead of only specific ones.

Edit: Specified that `<p>` tags can contain desirable numbers

Comment: Please let me know if my solution worked correct

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is:

1. Get the entire text.
2. Get the `p` elements containing `sup` or `a` with `footnotelink` class name texts.
3. From the former remove numbers.
4. From the entire text replace texts received in step 2 by texts received in step 3, as following:

```py
entire_text = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'divClass').text
psups = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='divClass']//p[.//sup]")
pas = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='divClass']//p[.//a[@class='footnotelink']]")
sub_texts = []
for ps in psups:
    sub_texts.append(ps.text)
for pa in pas:
    sub_texts.append(pa.text)
sut_text_cleaned = []
for sub in sub_texts:
    res = ''.join([i for i in sub if not i.isdigit()])
    sut_text_cleaned.append(res)
for i in range(len(sub_texts)):
    entire_text.replace(sub_texts[i], sut_text_cleaned[0])
```

Comment: I understand what you intend. Unfortunately I failed to mention that the <p> tags can contain desirable numbers that should not be removed. These numbers can appear in many different contexts (dates, page numbers, IDs...) so filtering them out is not feasible.
I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: OK, please define clearly where and how will appear numbers that we need to remove and where those that we have to keep.

Answer (score 0):

With regex

```
import re

article = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'divClass').text
article = re.sub(r'\d{1,}footnote', 'footnote', article)
print(article)
```

`\d{1,}footnote` means multiple (one ore more) digits just before the `footnote`.