# How to extract all direct text inside a tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to extract all direct text inside a td tag but I'm only able to get the first part of text by using this code.

```
td_tag = driver.find_element(By.ID, "td_id")
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild;', td_tag)['textContent']
```

Here is my DOM.

```
<td id="td_id">
  <p>Name</p>
  <div>
    <span>agdsf</span>
  </div>
  John Smith
  <span>dfsdf</span>
  Address:
  <br>
  NewYork
</td>
```

What I expect here is **Name John Smith Address: NewYork**

Comment: I notice you asked several questions, you received answers to them, but you never marked an answer as accepted. May I ask why is that? Are you aware of how this website works?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Yes, I know that. Because the answer does not work. Should I accept one of them even if none of them is working?

Comment: That's fine then, and only fair. I was concerned you are not aware you're meant to accept the answers which solve your issue.

Comment: Your question has been asked and successfully answered before, for example: [Python and Selenium - get text excluding child node's text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238364/python-and-selenium-get-text-excluding-child-nodes-text)

Comment: You say you only want the "direct" text, but in your example you are returning the text in a nested `p` element (but not in a nested `span` element). What is your actual requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all direct text inside the `td` tag, including text that is not enclosed in child tags, use JavaScript execution through Selenium to retrieve all child nodes of the `td` element and then concatenate their text content if they are text nodes. Following is the updated code:

```py
td_tag = driver.find_element(By.ID, "td_id")
all_text = driver.execute_script("""
    var node = arguments[0];
    var text = '';
    for (var child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            text += child.textContent.trim() + ' ';
        }
    }
    return text.trim();
""", td_tag)

print(all_text)  # This should print: "John Smith Address: NewYork"
```

The above script iterates through all child nodes of the `td` element. It checks if a child is a text node (using `child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE`) and, if so, appends its text content to the resulting string. The `trim` function in the loop is used to remove any extra whitespace and the `trim` function at the end is just used to remove the trailing extra whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium only supports XPath 1.0, which is very limited for this kind of thing. You're going to have to select a set of nodes in your XPath, and then concatenate their string values in the host language. I can't offer you more than that because I don't understand why you are selecting the `p` element child and not the `span` element child.