# selecting text node in selenium python with xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to select certain text that comes after an hr node with selenium and xpath. But I keep getting a WebDriverException

Here is the html code I want to extract the text from:
[html snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgT8e.png)

The text I want to get is: Introduction to financial ... business decisions

I used this code:

```
e = c.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ajaxcourseindentfix']/hr/following-sibling::text()")
```

The problem is that I keep getting this exception

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Text] {}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does `e = c.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.ajaxcourseindentfix").getText()` works?

Comment: Update your question with HTML code sample for `div` node as text

Comment: @Naramsim , there is no built-in `getText()` method in Python applicable to list

Comment: `e = c.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.ajaxcourseindentfix").text` sorry

Comment: @Naramsim, you're still trying to get text from list of elements. Anyway, even applied to single WebElement `text` property should return `"ACCT 200..."` and `"Credit hours"` text nodes which OP wants to skip...

Comment: try `e = c.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ajaxcourseindentfix']/hr/following-sibling::text()[1]").text`

Comment: @xruptronics That doesn't work either, I already tried it. If you want the link to the website, here it is: http://catalog.utk.edu/content.php?filter%5B27%5D=ACCT&filter%5B29%5D=&filter%5Bcourse_type%5D=-1&filter%5Bkeyword%5D=&filter%5B32%5D=1&filter%5Bcpage%5D=1&cur_cat_oid=16&expand=&navoid=1721&search_database=Filter#acalog_template_course_filter

Comment: Do not use following sibling , (//div[@class='ajaxcourseindentfix']/hr)[1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get text of an element in Selenium WebDriver, without including child element text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325454/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-without-including-child-ele)

Answer (score 1):

In selenium you cannot use XPath that returns attributes or text nodes, so `/text()` syntax is not allowed. If you want to get specific child text node (nodes) only instead of complete text content (returned by `text` property), you might execute complex JavaScript

I tried to implement solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705508/how-to-select-all-text-nodes-after-specific-element) and it seem to work, so you can apply below code to get required text node:

```
driver.execute_script("""var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
                         el.innerHTML = '<div>' + document.querySelector('div.ajaxcourseindentfix').innerHTML.split('<hr>')[1];
                         return el.querySelector( 'div' ).textContent;""")
```

The output is

```
Introduction to financial and managerial accounting theory and practice with emphasis on the role of accounting information in business decisions.
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML has 3 types node:  Element/Attribute/Text Node, Selenium's findElement require Element Node as return value.

In your XPath `text()` will select Text Node, that's why you get that error.

But we can use javascript to interact with Text Node.

```
script = """
    var text = '';

    var childNodes = arguments[0].childNodes; // child nodes includes Element and Text Node

    childNodes.forEach(function(it, index){
      if(it.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'HR') { // iterate until Element Node: hr
        text = childNodes[index+1].textContent; 
        // get the text content of next Child Node of Element Node: hr
      }
    });
    return text;
"""
ele = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.ajaxcourseindentfix")
text = driver.execute_script(script, ele)
print text
```