# How to select all text nodes after specific element

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<div class="someclass">
    <h3>First</h3> 
    <strong>Second</strong> 
    <hr>
    Third
    <br>
    Fourth
    <br>
    <em></em>
    ...
</div>
```

From above `div` node I want to get all child text nodes after `hr` (`"Third"`, `"Fourth"`, ... and there might be more)

If I do

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.someclass>hr~*')
```

I get `NodeList [ br, br, em, ... ]` - no text nodes

With below

```
document.querySelector('div.someclass').textContent
```

I get all text nodes as single string

I can get each text node as

```
var third = document.querySelector('div.someclass').childNodes[6].textContent
var fourth = document.querySelector('div.someclass').childNodes[8].textContent
```

so I tried

```
document.querySelector('div.someclass').childNodes[5:]  # SyntaxError
```

and [`slice()`](https://www.hacksparrow.com/javascript-slice-with-examples.html)

```
document.querySelector('div.someclass').childNodes.slice(5)  # TypeError
```

So is there any way I can get all child text nodes starting from `hr` node?

*UPDATE*

I forgot to mention that this question is about web-scraping, but not web-development... I cannot change HTML source code

Comment: " I get NodeList [ br, br, em, ... ] - no text nodes " maybe just put the text into `<p>` tags and they will also be returned?

Comment: @messerbill, Sorry, I didn't mention that this question is about web-scraping, but not web-development.. I cannot change HTML source code

Comment: how about `S(".someClass").text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the content and use split with `hr` to get the html after the `hr` and then replace this content within a `div` and you will be able to manipulate this `div` to get your content:

```js
var content = document.querySelector('.someclass').innerHTML;
content = content.split('<hr>');
content = content[1];

document.querySelector('.hide').innerHTML = content;
/**/

var nodes = document.querySelector('.hide').childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  console.log(nodes[i].textContent);
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass">
  <h3>First</h3>
  <strong>Second</strong>
  <hr> Third
  <br> Fourth
  <br>
  <em></em> ...
</div>
<div class="hide"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.childNodes` includes both text and non-text nodes.

Your syntax error is because you can't do array slicing like `[5:]` in javascript.

And also a NodeList is array-like...but is not an array...which is why `slice` doesn't work directly on `childNodes`.

**1) get your NodeList**

```js
var nodeList = document.querySelector('.some-class').childNodes;
```

**2) Convert NodeList to actual array**

```js
nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
```

(note in modern ES6 browsers you can do `nodes = Array.from(nodes);`
Also modern browsers have added `.forEach` support to NodeList objects...so you can directly use `.forEach` without array conversion on NodeList in modern browsers)

**3) Iterate and collect the text nodes you want**

This is dependent on your own logic.  But you can iterate the nodes and test to see if `node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE` to see if any given node is a text node.

```js
var foundHr = false,
    results = [];
nodes.forEach(el => {
    if (el.tagName == 'HR') { foundHr = true; }
    else if (foundHr && el.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        results.push(el.textContent);
    }
});
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get all text nodes under `node` using this piece of code:

```js
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(node, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
var textNode;
var result = [];
while (textNode = walker.nextNode()) {
    result.push(textNode);
}
```

And you've got an `Array` of text nodes, so you can `slice()` it as you wish:

```js
console.log(result.slice(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another [Recursive] Solution

```
const { childNodes } = <Element>document.querySelector('.someclass');  // throws an error if element doesn't exist
const siblings = sliceNodeList([], false, 'hr', ...childNodes);

function sliceNodeList(nodes: Node[], deep: boolean, selector: string, node?: Node, ...more: Node[]) {
    if (!selector) return nodes;
    if (!node) return nodes;
    const { nodeType } = node;
    const handle = {  // not concerned with Attr Nodes
        [Node.ELEMENT_NODE]: handleElement,
        [Node.TEXT_NODE]: handleOther,
        [Node.COMMENT_NODE]: handleOther,
    }[ nodeType ];
    
    if (handle) handle.call(this, nodes, deep, selector, node);
    if (more.length) sliceNodeList(nodes, deep, selector, ...more);
    return nodes;
}

function handleElement(nodes: Node[], deep: boolean, selector: string, node: Element) {
    const { childNodes } = node;  // not concerned with Attr Nodes
    const matches = node.matches(selector);
    
    if (nodes.length) nodes.push(node);  // assume we must have already matched
    else if (matches) nodes.push(node);  // we matched on an element
    
    if (deep) sliceNodeList(nodes, deep, selector, ...childNodes);  // keep diving into substructures
    return nodes;
}

function handleOther(nodes: Node[], deep: boolean, selector: string, node: Text|Comment) {
    if (nodes.length) return [ ...nodes, node ];  // assume we must have already matched
    if (node.data === selector) return [ ...nodes, node ];  // we matched on a Text or Comment value
    return nodes;
}
```

Basically, this just uses recursion by checking if there are more siblings while mapping to the correct Node-Type's handler. It uses Mutual Recursion (if `deep === true`) by recalling the parent function to dive into nested structures. We didn't concern ourselves here with `Attr` `Node`s, but you can setup a handler for that.

Because a `Text` and a `Comment` share enough of the same interface (`node.data`) we are able to reuse the same function. That function, similar to `handleElement`, assumes that `if (nodes.length)` then we've already matched and can safely & reliably add the current node to the collection.

Unlike `handleElement`, a `Text` or `Comment` cannot call `node.matches`. However, we can still match on the node if it's value is equal to the `selector` -- *giving us the ability to select by text*. We could go another step further here by, instead of using a strict equality on the entire text (or comment) value using `===`, we could use something like `String.prototype.includes` or a `RegExp`.

We could have used `for`, `while`, or other iteration approaches. It seems to me, however, that recursion is a better approach to walking the DOM as the DOM is compositive (`Node` implements *The Composite Pattern*) and thus a recursive structure. I also just whipped this out in VSCode very quickly and didn't even run it in a browser console, but I write this pattern all the time so it should be pretty close to good-to-go.

Hopefully helpfully.