# Retrieve Text Between Two Child Elements With Text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm wondering if there is any way to easily retrieve text that is sandwiched between two child elements with text? In this particular case, I'm looking to extract the text `USD`.

```
<div class="indemandProgress-raised ng-binding">
    <span class="indemandProgress-raisedAmount ng-binding" gogo-test="raised">
        $6,811,034
    </span>
    USD
    <span class="ng-binding">
        total funds raised
    </span>
</div>
```

Actual Format of Code in Browser

```
<div class="indemandProgress-raised ng-binding">
<span class="indemandProgress-raisedAmount ng-binding" gogo-test="raised">$6,811,034</span> USD <span class="ng-binding">total funds raised</span>
</div>
```

Is this possible with XPATH alone or would I have to extract all of the text and then parse it?

**It has to work with Selenium.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like using xpath 2.0+:

```
//div[@class="indemandProgress-raised ng-binding"]/text()
```

[**Test Demo**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22indemandProgress-raised%20ng-binding%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22indemandProgress-raisedAmount%20ng-binding%22%20gogo-test%3D%22raised%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%246%2C811%2C034%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%20%20%20USD%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22ng-binding%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20total%20funds%20raised%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22indemandProgress-raised%20ng-binding%22%3E&extract=%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22indemandProgress-raised%20ng-binding%22%5D%2Ftext()&=%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22indemandProgress-raised%20ng-binding%22%5D%2Ftext()&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)

---

In Selenium, you cannot use XPath that returns Attributes or Text nodes, since only Nodes are supported.

To get the text you want you can use Javascript to extract it from the Text Node.
Or select the node and then use `.text`

```
result = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "indemandProgress-raisedAmount")]').text.split()[1]
```

So, ultimately, it is not possible using XPath /text() in Selenium and you have to rely on alternatives methods as outlined.

Comment: already tried it. doesn't work with selenium. i guess i should've added that to the question. myb. if you're interested: `WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Text] {}`

Comment: you can select Text nodes with `.text`... anyways, the JS is useless since i can simply use `x = browser.find_element_by_xpath(...).text.split()[1]`.

Comment: "it is not possible using XPath /text() in Selenium"

Comment: so it's definitively impossible with xpath in a selenium environment?

Comment: According to my (limited) knowledge, unfortunately, that's the case. Here is an [answer that states the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706495/8291949).

Answer (score 1):

You've already accepted answer, but note that `text.split()[1]` is quite unreliable solution and it might not be applicable in other (in most) cases. For instance, if first text node contains spaces

```
$ 6,811,034
```

You can try this solution:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('indemandProgress-raisedAmount')
result = browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', element).strip()
```

Note that `div` has following 5 child nodes:

1. Empty string (index `0`)
2. `span` node (index `1`)
3. Text node `"USD"` (index `2`)
4. Another `span` (index `3`)
5. Another empty string (index `4`)

You need to get text content of third child node and `childNodes[2].textContent` allows you to do that

Comment: def good to know, but out of hundreds of cases `browser.find_element_by_xpath(...).text` always returns output akin to `$107,866 USD total funds raised`.

Comment: in your example, `result = browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', element).strip()`, is `element` passed in as `arguments`?

Comment: Yep. `arguments[0] == element`. It's just a simplified syntax for `browser.execute_script('return document.querySelector(".indemandProgress-raisedAmount").childNodes[2].textContent;').strip()`

Comment: ok interesting. thats pretty cool how u can select an element with selenium, store it as a variable, and then pass it to javascript as the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with XPath alone but you can use Javascript Executor and get the text node. You didn't specify a language so here's a method to do this in C#:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the text of the specified child text node.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parentElement">The parent <see cref="IWebElement"/> of the desired text node.</param>
/// <param name="index">The index of the childNode collection relative to parentElement</param>
/// <returns>The text of the specified child text node.</returns>
public string GetChildTextNode(IWebElement parentElement, int index = 0)
{
    string s = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[arguments[1]].textContent;", parentElement, index);
    return s.Trim();
}
```

In this case you would call it like

```
IWebElement e = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.indemandProgress-raised"));
string s = GetChildTextNode(e, 2);
```

Comment: myb. ive added a python tag