# How can i get text from class using selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium

```
<div class="class-one">
<div class="class-two">
sample text
<div class="class-three">
<a href="https://google.com" target="" class="button button--outline button--purple " id="" title="search"><i class="fal fa-fw fa-file-word"></i><span class="button__title">search</span></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

When i do `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.class-two')` it prints `sample text` and `search` too, how can i get only sample text using selenium in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get text of an element in Selenium WebDriver, without including child element text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325454/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-without-including-child-ele)

Answer (score 1):

You need only write "text" in end.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.class-two').text
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Change
find_elements_by_css_selector 
to
find_element_by_css_selector

Comment: it also shows sample text and search, but i need only sample text

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.class-two').text.split("\n")[0]