# Get Text from an element with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to get the *text* of an element with Selenium.

Element:

```html
<p
    class="sc-168cvuh-1 cNxwvb">

    <svg
        aria-hidden="true"
        focusable="false"
        data-prefix="fas"
        data-icon="circle"
        class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 fa-fw sc-168cvuh-2 frUsNu"
        role="img"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 512 512"
        _css="[object Object],[object Object]">
        <path
            fill="currentColor"
            d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z">
        </path>
    </svg>&nbsp;running</p>
```

I want to get the "running" from the element.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get text of an element in Selenium WebDriver, without including child element text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325454/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-without-including-child-ele)

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @0stone0 No that didnt work. @ itronic1990 I tiried getting the whole Class by Xpath and than getting the Text with: "statustext.text"

Comment: Look at this answer, is really helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824928/get-text-from-an-element-with-selenium-python

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824928/get-text-from-an-element-with-selenium-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
desired_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'sc-')]"))).text
print(desired_text)
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: No, im getting the Error: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.support.wait' has no attribute 'until' But that is an Error with the Script i think

Comment: Now i get: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'visibility_of_element_located'

Comment: make sure imports should be correct. `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`