# select any element that has text in webdriver

Tags: java, text, localization, webdriver

I'm looking to implement a general localisation test using webdriver and my idea is:

1. Select all elements that contain text
2. Use a java language identification library to verify that the text is in some specific language

I looked up various ways to select elements using text but everything documented seems to show ways of locating using specific text using contains() or text()

I thought the following would work:

```
//*[contains(text(), '')]
```

but that selects everything whether it has text or not. It also selects elements in the header. I want to select all visible text on the page, extract that text and pass it through the language identification library element by element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath

```
//*[text() != ""]
```

This will give you all the elements with non-empty text.
So that

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text() != '']"));
```

will give you a list of all web elements on the page containing texts.
**UPD**
If you wish to get only elements containing texts themselves, you can exclude the elements containing texts in their children only by this code:

```
List<WebElement> real = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement element : list){
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    String text = js.executeScript("""
    return jQuery(arguments[0]).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
    }).text();
    """, element);
    if(text.length()>0){
        real.add(element);
}
```

The final list of elements will be in `real` list.
The idea is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040341/3485434). Translated from Python to Java according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11439939/3485434) syntax

Comment: Its better than mine but from inspect it still hits the header, the title and all of the style elements in the header. Is there a way to limit to the body? However inspired by you I tried //body//*[text() != ""] and this worked

Comment: So, now you found what you looked for or still want to improve it to get only elements containing texts themselves, not containing texts in their child nodes?

Comment: yes I would rather get the elements with the texts themselves

Comment: I didn't find better solution than this. Please see the updated answer

Comment: I see, thanks. I already upvoted you, so can't do that anymore 