# Selenium Python : get text inside an element but not under the tags inside it

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xml, selenium

I have an element

```
'<div class="ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua">₹199 <span class="ProductVariants__MRPText-sc-1unev4j-10 jEinXG">₹690</span></div>'
```

I need to get `₹199` which is outside any tag. But when I do

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua']").text
```

I get

```
'₹199 ₹690'
```

But what I need is only outer text that is `₹199`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325454/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-without-including-child-ele) can also help you.

Summary:

```
def select_text(driver, element):
    return driver.execute_script("""
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var ret = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                ret += child.textContent;
            child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return ret;
    """, element)

select_text(driver, driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua']"))
>>> '₹199 '
```

---

[Original idea, that doesn't work with selenium directly for me]

You can add to your XPath, that you only want the text content(s) of the node you found.

EDIT: It seems that selenium won't do that by itself. Besides executing some javascript as in the other thread, you could take the html and parse it again:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

your_element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua']")
ET.fromstring(your_element.get_attribute("outerHTML")).xpath("text()")
>>> ['₹199 ']
```

Comment: This gives me error `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@class='ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua']/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.`

Comment: @GABDA true, i didn't test with selenium initially and didn't know it doesn't allow for that. I added another source (and for completeness a fix for the initial attempt).