# Click button by text using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Is it possible to click multiply buttons with the same text with [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29)?

[image: Text = Unlock this result here]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can find all buttons by text and then execute `click()` method for each button in a `for` loop.
Using this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth) it would be something like this:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'My Button')]")

for btn in buttons:
    btn.click()
```

I also recommend you take a look at [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) which is a nice wrapper for Selenium.

> Splinter is an abstraction layer on top of existing browser automation
>   tools such as Selenium, PhantomJS and zope.testbrowser. It has a
>   high-level API that makes it easy to write automated tests of web
>   applications.

Comment: Well, they're about 100 different buttons I have to click, and they all have different xpathas

Comment: But they have the same text/look the same

Comment: In the example I've given, you're not looking for a given *absolute* xpath, but for text that buttons contain.

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Unlock this result here')]").click()
Not working, I don't understand?

Comment: Could you provide us with a link to the website you try to interact with? Or show us html code of buttons?

Answer (score 10):

To locate and click a `<button>` element by it's text you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `text()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='button_text']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(., 'button_text')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate and click a `<button>` element by it's text you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH* and `text()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='button_text']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `contains()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'button_text')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

To locate all the `<button>` elements by the text you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `text()`:

  ```
  for button in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[text()='button_text']"):
    button.click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  for button in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(., 'button_text')]"):
    button.click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate all the `<button>` elements by the text you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH* and `text()`:

  ```
  for button in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='button_text']"))):
    button.click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `contains()`:

  ```
  for button in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'button_text')]"))):
    button.click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 8):

I had the following in html:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "HELLO")]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

@nobodyskiddy, Try to use `driver.find_element` ( if you have a single button option ), use index to `click()` when you are using `driver.find_elements`, `find_elements` will return array to web element values, so you have to use the index to select or click.

Answer (score -1):

```
CheckElementAttribute(driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnCopyBtn")), "enabled", "true", "Copy  Type field");
```

Comment: You can consider elaborating your answer about how to make use of the code you've provided.