# No Id, No name. How to click this button?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with python to navigate through a site and I can not figure out how to select this button.

```
<button onclick="addAutoTrade();blur();" type="button" style="background-
color:#c7c7c7;">Add</button>
```

The button is surrounded by a class but within the class are 2 buttons.
I have tried using

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Add")
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Add")
driver.find_element_by_name("Add")
```

There is no obvious id so I am stuck and I apologize if this is trivial. How can I click this button?

Comment: Is the context of the button always the same, so does an xpath work?

Comment: i encountered something like this once and the only thing that worked was this `//button[contains(.,'Add')]` . try it out

Comment: @RayhaneMama with an xpath?

Comment: I'm sorry, Yes  @NickPavini

Comment: @RayhaneMama Like this? driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Add')]"). If so still no luck

Comment: if it is the first item you're looking for on the actual page you should put it in a wait like `WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Add')]")))`

Comment: @RayhaneMama no luck. That code actually is not even recognized so I'm assuming I need to import something else? I appreciate you helping me btw.

Comment: @syntonym the xpath, if I am on the right track, doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Can you construct the xpath completly, so something like `/div/div/div/nav[3]/button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, hope this works for you:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

buttonXpath = "//button[contains(.,'Add')]"

element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,buttonXpath)))
element.click()
```

You can learn more about waits [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) and check selenium [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html). these are quite usefull.
You can also see these topics about selecting buttons by text, they might help:

[topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470171/click-button-by-text-using-python-and-selenium)
[topic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth)