# press a button with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

[image]

I want the bot to click on male
But I don't know how I tried to use this, but it didn't work for me

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='sex']").click()
```

I want a command to make the bot click on male in Python.

Comment: This looks like a previously asked question, take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470171/click-button-by-text-using-python-and-selenium

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to click on 'Male' radio-button try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[.='Male']/following-sibling::input[@name='sex']").click()
```