# Trouble retrieving this element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
<a href="arbitraryURL.com;Token=1" target="_top" h="ID=123,5088.1">Sign in</a>
```

Hey Guys,

Pretty simple question here but I'm having trouble with it for some odd reason. What is the best way to "grab" this button in selenium (using python but a generalized solution would work as well). Its a button, but its html is not a button which means this has not been working for me.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Sign in"]')
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it using the `a` tag instead of `button` like this

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Sign in')]")
```

[Selenium docs on locating elements by XPath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)

and

[A good SO answer to help locate an element that contains given text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and precise answer. Makes a lot of sense.