# How to extract the ID attribute of a DOM element, if i know corresponding text through Selenium Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, getattribute

I used following code:

```
driver.getPageSource().contains("My value in text box");
```

This will let me know, element present in dom or not.

Now, i need to know , value containing text-box "My value in text box". What is id of this text box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find an element that contains specific text in Selenium Webdriver (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the *id* of a *dom element* you don't need to invoke `getPageSource()`. You can simply use the `getAttribute()` method as follows:

```
String elementID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'My value in text box')]")).getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: Just a caveat: sometimes the text is contained in a label, not an input element. However, it is common practice for that label to have a "for" attribute which does contain the ID for the input element.  I would check the tag of the returned xpath first to see if it's a label and then get the actual input via ID, otherwise it would be fairly safe to assume it's what you were looking for.