# Is there a way to write a piece of python code to see if a series of words exist on a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if there is a way to see if a series of words exist on a web page using python.

For example, is there a way to write a function that will return true iff the words 'this site is good' are found on a given web page?

Ideally I would want this to work using a web page in the chrome browser, and I am only worried about the same text that would show up if you used ctrl+f in chrome.

Thanks!

Initially I thought that you could use pynput to manually ctrl+f in chrome but I don't know how you would get a function to return true if the results of chrome's find feature are true.

Comment: You can use **regex** in python to find the words and match it. For extracting the words/content from website you can go with `urllib` , `requests` , and many packages.

Comment: What amrs-tech said with a caveat, if the text is generated using JS you will have to use a a few more packages

Answer (score 0):

As show here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968429/12044063), you can use `BeautifulSoup` which is a HTML parsing package and a package like `urllib` or `Requests` in order to get the page itself.

Alternatively, you could use `Selenium` or `Requestium`, which is a mix between `Selenium` and `Requests`, in order to do that as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701085/12044063)

Then you just needed to

```py
def selenium_code():
    pass

if selenium_code == True:
    print("The words have been found")
```