# Selecting dynamic element using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, dynamic, selection

Could someone please tell me how can I select a dynamic element using selenium?

I would like to select the "limit-order" element.

```
<div class="tab-control" id="uniqName_0_85" widgetid="uniqName_0_85">
    <span data-tab="market-order" class="tab-item tab-active">Market</span>
    <span data-tab="limit-order" class="tab-item">Limit</span>
    <span data-tab="stop-order" class="tab-item">Stop</span>
    <span data-tab="stop_limit-order" class="tab-item">Stop Limit</span>
</div>
```

I tried this but no luck:

```
btn_limit_name_xpath = '//div[contains(@class,"tab-control")]/span[2]'
btn_limit = browser.find_element_by_xpath(btn_limit_name_xpath)
btn_limit.click()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find an element that contains specific text in Selenium Webdriver (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sometimes does the job for me is copy the full xpath instead of the shorter one.

If that doesn't work either, you could try and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth) out.

They show you how you can use an xpath to find a specific piece of text and select the object in that way. So in your case you could try and find it by searching for 'limit'.

Comment: Hey, Thank you. The copying the full path did not work but I could use the information the link, and now my program is working.