# How can I click contains this?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

I have following HTML:

```html
<pre>
<div class="selected_text">
   <span class="memo">
   <span class="title">01.</span>I want This
   </span>
   <span class="blank"></span>
   <span class="price">
   100
   </span>
</div>
<pre>
```

I want to find the string that contains text `I want this` and click it.

So I try to use

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"want")]').click()`

But It's not working

How can i perform click on this element ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find an element that contains specific text in Selenium Webdriver (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth)

Comment: What do you mean by click it? The html you have give inst a clickable element.

Comment: Agree with @ChrisDoyle, the HTML you given seems `not clickable`. So you first check for `clickability`

Comment: @Gilb _But It's not working_, what error do you see?

Comment: @DebanjanB when I try to "driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span').get_attribute("text")", not response... "driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span/span').get_attribute("text")" -> '01' //Sorry for not explaining well in English.

Comment: but "driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"01")]').click()" is worked. I want to click using "I want This"

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is an issue with your xpath. Use `.` instead of `text()` in contains method. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862373/5097027) answer to identify difference between them.

Use explicit wait to avoid unnecessary timeout related things.

Refer below code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 45).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'I want This')]"))).click()
```