# Finding Spans that contain the text IMG, Java Selenium with chromedriver

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My program needs to find a series of Spans that their text starts with IMG. The table will potentially have multiple spans that meet this criteria. Example Formatting being:

```
<td>
  <span> IMG Sales Report </span>
</td>
```

I have tried several different lines of code, but i always end up with results being zero. Heres my latest attempt.

```
List<WebElement> files = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(text(), 'IMG')]"));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cause I cant find a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.There is leading space in front of IMG.

```
//span[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'IMG')]
```

> Output

[image: Output from xpath formatter]

Answer (score 0):

To print the *List* of **id** *attribute* of the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use *Java8* [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `starts-with()`:

  ```
  List<String> myIDs = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(., 'IMG')]")));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  List<String> myIDs = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//td/span[contains(., 'IMG')]")));
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How do I find an element that contains specific text in Selenium Webdriver (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth/59698552#59698552)