# Python Selenium - Close Driver When Text is no longer found

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Hi I am using selenium to automate test on web pages. I am using selenium and python and would like to have answers in this framework only. I run looping script to check if text is still found or not, if not then close the browser.I have tried my script but only working when text has link on it

```
    while True:
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "My Text"))  
            )
    
        except:
            break
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

that script is working when text has link, The problem is my text was pure text without any link. i cannot use css selector because the text changing after certain minutes, so i need to locate text not xpath or other. Hope someone can help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT` which is designed to only find text inside links.
If you want to lookup text in all elements, you need to use `XPATH`:

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'My Text')]"))
```

See for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701085/14241710

Comment: i did this, but driver wont close when text is changing. Did i miss something?

Comment: this is xpath of my text by the way
//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string/text()

Comment: almost working, it close after i click on different address, but won't close it self when text is changing,, any sugets?

Comment: Ps. i need to refresh the page so driver will close

Answer (score 0):

try that out, might help:

```
def check_no_longer_present(text):
   try:
       if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[contains(text(), '{}')".format(text)).is_displayed():
           return False
   except NoSuchElementException:
       return True

if check_no_longer_present('you_text'):
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: where should i put my text?

Comment: @MukhammadAnwarFuadi do you know text of the element???

Comment: i mean, you have {}} on "//[contains(text(), '{}}')", should i replace it with my text? i tried change you_text on if check_no_longer_present('you_text') whit my text but still not working,, did i miss something? thanks

Comment: @MukhammadAnwarFuadi you just need to use check_no_longer_present('you_text'), where you_test - is your test of the element

Comment: "//[contains(text(), '{}}').format() will put the text to the selector automatically

Comment: I see... so i just need to change ‘you_tex’ with “My Text” ?

Comment: @MukhammadAnwarFuadi copy html part where your element located

Comment: its came to error 
"if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[contains(text(), '{}}')".format(text)).is_displayed():
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string"

Comment: @MukhammadAnwarFuadi my fault, there was 1 useless '}', have you ever worked with python and format statement?

Comment: @MukhammadAnwarFuadi I have updated the code

Comment: yeah thats why i ask about {}} because i think 1 } is useles,, i'm new on python by the way,, "copy html part where your element located" do you mean the "Text" or what? because i have problem with that, when i run it automatically close even the text is still appear