# Selenium WebDriver Validating Error Message Text

Tags: c#, selenium, validation

Please I am trying to validate error message text in a try catch and it is just catching every time. Need assistance with syntax or better way of the validation

```
string actualResultText = "";
string expectedResultText = "Error: Please Enter User Name";
IWebElement actualResult = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='id-7530880b3e6759b']/li/span[contains(text(),'Error: Please Enter User Name')]"));

actualResultText=actualResult.ToString();

if (actualResultText == expectedResultText)
{
    result = true;
}
    else
{
    result = false;
}
```

Inspect
[Please view this inspect against code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iybJl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with selenium in python, but the answer might have something similar in C#.
In python, in order to get the text of an element you use:

```py
element = driver.find_element(by, value)  # get the element
print(element.text)  # get the text of the element
```

The difference between here and what you are doing (again, if C# has something similar and it works the way I think it is) is using the attribute of the element object `text`, rather than converting the element object into a string.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. The issue I have is related to the IWebElement syntax to find the element correctly. I did post the inspect as well to see if anyone can show/tell me where I am in error. I get kicked to the catch block after IWebElement line.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wish to find an element based on the text presented. If so, please go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701085/14947575