# How to get a text from html using Selenium WebDriver with python-Using CSS selector

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Anyone know how to get the text from the below html code. Just I need '383' as a text by using CSS selector from the below html.

```
<td align="right" style="background-color: rgb(147, 191, 179); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xpath="1">383&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Is that all the HTML you've? for the better locator, please share bit more outerHTML

Comment: @cruisepandey Okay .. using CSS selector via style and align ="right" attributes .so can we write css selector path.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth

Comment: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

First start the webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

your_chromedriver_path = '...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(your_chromedriver_path))
```

then load the webpage

```
url = '...'
driver.get(url)
```

then find the `td` element

```
td = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td')
```

finally you can get its text by using one of the following (see differences [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp))

```
td.text
td.get_attribute('innerHTML')
td.get_attribute('innerText')
td.get_attribute('textContent')
```

Comment: Can i find out the particular td element

Comment: @vipinsharma what is the full html code?