# Click on the button with Selenium, using the button text as a search element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping

I would like to click on the Google "News" button (after searching for something). I would like to search using the text `News` (in my case "Notizie") as an element. Google sometimes changes the names of the elements, so I would like to use the "News" element because it is always the same

I use this, but it doesn't work:

```
WebDriverWait (driver, 20) .until (EC.element_to_be_clickable ((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div [aria-label = 'News']"))). Click ()
```

How can I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the div tools, right click on that element and hover over copy and select copy by CSS selector, then use that in your scripts.

Comment: @Hannon qaoud I know, but I wasn't looking for this way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find an element that contains specific text in Selenium WebDriver (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth)

Comment: @Hannon qaoud Google sometimes changes the names of the elements, so I would like to use the "News" element because it is always the same. Now check your links. Thank you

Comment: @Hannon qaoud  No, I have not risen to my question

Comment: sorry, I am not sure I understand? so the link doesn't help? if so please explain one more time what is that you are trying to do.

Comment: @Hannon qaoud No, the links not helped. The links come close to what I'm looking for, but they don't help. As you know, there are various ways to click on a button, I want to use a way that directly uses the name "News". I don't want to right click on an item and select something, but I want to use the name "News" directly. Also, I look for WebDriverWait (driver, 20) .until (EC.element_to_be_clickable, while in your links there was driver.find_element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delay.

after understanding you correctly, you want to search for an element by its text and click on it.

for the record, you use `WebDriverWait (driver, 20) .until (EC.element_to_be_clickable` while its a great practice you need to understand that if its your first click, then the driver will not click until all elements are visible, and therefore `driver.find_element().click()` does the same job

also a quick disclaimer, not all google searches show the "news" button in the options bar, and here's a sample code of what you want.

```
from time import sleep
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=weather')
newsButton = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'News')
newsButton.click()
sleep(5)
```

you look for an element by its text with `By.LINK_TEXT`

and here's your code it it:

```
WebDriverWait (driver, 20) .until (EC.element_to_be_clickable ((By.LINK_TEXT, "News"))). Click ()
```

also check out `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`

good luck and sorry again for the misunderstanding, happy coding :)

## update

it seems that the `By.LINK_NAME` filter only finds elements by text that are links, or in a `<a>` tag, and that's why it wont catch the "Tools" button, but the tools button is static, therefor you can access it with a normal `css selector` or `xpath`

Comment: Thank you. Using the same method, do you know why clicking on the News Tools button doesn't work? I wrote tools = WebDriverWait (driver, 20) .until (EC.element_to_be_clickable ((By.LINK_TEXT, "Tools"))). Click (), I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, the answer has been updated

Comment: I'm trying to use tools = WebDriverWait (driver, 20) .until (EC.element_to_be_clickable ((By.XPATH, '// * [@ id = "hdtb-tls"]'))). Click (), but it doesn't work either . Maybe the problem is with the menu expansion function?

Comment: ```tools = driver.find_element(By.ID, "hdtb-tls")tools.click()``` try this

Comment: It does not work. The Tools button is selected and colored with a gray rectangle, but it is not clicked

Comment: are you sure of the expected behavior? try to click it manually and see what happens, then report back if it doesn't do the same with the script.

Comment: If I manually click on Tools, it works. If I click manually, the Google News menu opens (like a horizontal drop-down menu). Using the script, it doesn't open, it just colors Tools with a gray rectangle

Comment: If you want to help me, I posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848713/pull-down-buttons-do-not-open-with-selenium-html-element-name-correct-but-some I'll be happy to accept this other answer as well if you help me