# Pull-down buttons do not open with Selenium. Html element name correct, but something is wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

After opening the Google News section, I would like to click on the `Tools` button, then `All results` and finally `Past 24 hours`. I'd rather use the `By.LINK_TEXT` mode as a show in the code.

The News button **works fine, everything ok**. The problem is that the buttons are not clicked. The problem does not concern By.LINK_TEXT, because I have also tried with CSS_SELECTOR and XPATH. There is something wrong. Can you help me? Below I attach the code and the screenshot to make you understand where I would like to click. Again, I would prefer a solution with By.LINK_TEXT

**NOTE:** The words to be searched for are previously entered via a variable that is automatically inserted in the Google search textbox, so as a solution I cannot enter the words to be searched for in the link

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")    

word = "example"

insert_word = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q')
insert_word.send_keys(word)  

insert_word.submit()
```

Code

```
news = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "News"))).click()

tools = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Tools"))).click()

recent = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "All results"))).click()

past24hours = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Past 24 hours"))).click()
```

[image]

Comment: add `&tbs=qdr:d` to the link it will do the job
`https://www.google.com/search?q=example&tbs=qdr:d`

Comment: @Hanna where should i add it?

Comment: @Hanna It works, but it's not what I wanted, because I enter the words to search above like this: insert_word = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q'), insert_word.send_keys(word), insert_word.submit()

Comment: yes you can, just do another ```driver.get('new url with q and tbs and qdr')```

Comment: @Hannon qaoud Are you sure I should create another driver? I have updated the code to show how I enter the words to search on Google. Why should I insert another driver when the page is always Google?

Answer (score 0):

hey max how about instead of entering the search query (word) manually, u feed it directly to the url, then u do the `driver.get()` and while your at it, since you know you want the news page and the past 24 hours, you can also feed these parameters to the url as well, so the code will look somthing like this:

```
from time import sleep
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
word = "example"
url = "https://www.google.com/search"
url += "?q=" + word # the search word
url += "&tbm=nws" # the news page
url += "&hl=en"  # language
url += "&tbs=qdr:d" # the past 24 hours
# url devided to dowmain and arguments
# tbs : qdr:h -> time range: last hour
# tbs : qdr:d -> time range: last day
# tbs : qdr:m -> time range: last mounth
# tbs : qdr:y -> time range: last year
# tbs : ar:1 -> time range: archive
# tbm : nws ->type: news
# tbm : blg ->type: blog
# tbm : vid ->type: video
# tbm : isch ->type: image
# q : query to search for (search term)
driver.get(url)

sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a bit of a forced solution, but I'll keep it in mind. I'll let you know tomorrow

Comment: In the meantime, I have voted for your kind answer. How can I click on the button to accept Google cookies? Your code is blocked by cookies. I've been trying in various ways, but strangely, I can't. Thank you