# Selenium Python: How to capture li element with specific text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, normalize-space

I am trying to extract `urlToBeCaptured` and `Text to be captured` from the HTML. The structure looks as follows:

```
<li>
  " text with trailing spaces "
  <a href="urlToBeCaptured">
    <span class ="class1> Text to be captured </span>
    <span class ="class2> Another text </span>
  </a>
...
</li>
```

I am doing the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(),'text with trailing spaces')]")
```

Once I locate the element how to extract the text from class1, should it be something like this?

```
textToBeCaptured = el.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'class1').text
```

Comment: Too many questions in one ticket. Reduce the number of questions to a single to recieve canonical answer.

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the HTML:

```
<li>
    text with trailing spaces 
    <a href="urlToBeCaptured">
        <span class ="class1"> Text to be captured </span>
        <span class ="class2"> Another text </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

To locate the node with text *" text with trailing spaces "* and then it's descendent `<span>` with `class ="class1"` you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *XPATH* and `contains()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(., 'text with trailing spaces')]/a//span[@class='class1']").text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and [`normalize-space()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59698552/7429447):

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(normalize-space(),'text with trailing spaces')]/a//span[@class='class1']").text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

---

### Update

From the [website](https://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/office/417178/bonallack-bishop) to retrive the text *`1 person`* from *"Areas of practice at this organisation"* with *Advocacy* you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/office/417178/bonallack-bishop")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#ccc-notify-accept > span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[normalize-space()='Areas of practice at this organisation']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='open']//ul/li[contains(.,'Advocacy')]/a[contains(@href, 'Practice')]/span[@class='accredited-pad']"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1 person
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I am clearly doing something wrong here as I receive NoSuchElementException :( I am using XPATH and normalize-space()

Comment: @bekon How about the `contains()` clause?

Comment: both don't seem to work. I am trying to get the link to people practicing advocacy from the following link https://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/office/417178/bonallack-bishop under the Areas of practice at this organisation

Comment: @bekon Within "Facilities at this office" section there are 2 sub-sections containing "Advocacy" i.e. "Areas of practice at this branch" and "Areas of practice at this organisation"? Which sub-section?

Comment: Areas of practice at this organisation

Comment: @bekon I don't find 2 child `<span>` within an `<a>` for 1 person at BONALLACK & BISHOP with area of practice: Advocacy
Timothy John Bishop
Solicitor Admitted as a solicitor 15/02/88

Comment: What I actually need is just a number of people practicing advocacy, so in this case 1 person. The full XPath is the following /html/body/div[5]/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/section[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span[1], but I need to extract it programmatically