# Reviews button is not clicking on google map

Tags: python, google-maps, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to click Google Maps Company's `Reviews` button and after that extract 10 reviews description with selenium python.

**An example link is given below:**

> https://www.google.com/maps/place/PakDeZon+B.V./@52.7092108,4.9585823,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x47c8acebaea7c103:0xb4e4a90c507e03a2!8m2!3d52.7092108!4d4.9585823!16s%2Fg%2F11c3k693v6?authuser=0&hl=en&entry=ttu

**I tryed this way.**

```
def get_reviews(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(4)
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/span[1]/span')
    button.click()

    time.sleep(5)
```

[image]

Comment: That nested divs approach is just asking for typos and errors. Maybe try [searching it by text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth) ("Reviews")

Answer (score 1):

That Xpath looks autogenerated by a tool and it won't work as it heavily depends on website structure and selenium browser sees a different HTML from what you see. It will also be broken the second google modified the HTML in any way.

Have a look at the functions available on [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions).

You can probably simplify your Xpath to
`//span[contains(text(),'Reviews')]` or `//*[contains(text(),'Reviews')]` if you want to be super safe

Answer (score 1):

Review tab locator is `[role=tab][aria-label*=Reviews]`

You should click on it, wait until all items with locator `.MyEned` are rendered and then get their texts in loop.

Rendering condition can be wait for collection of elements to stop changing along some time interval or any other approach like waiting for review content loader to be hidden, etc.

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def wait_for_value_to_stop_changing(value_func, timeout=10, interval=2):
    start_time = time.time()
    value = None
    while value_func() != value:
        value = value_func()
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            raise TimeoutError("Timeout: Value did not stop changing within the specified time.")
        time.sleep(interval)
    return value

def get_reviews():
    return wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.MyEned')))


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(
    "https://www.google.com/maps/place/PakDeZon+B.V./@52.7092108,4.9585823,17z/data=!4m8!3m7!1s0x47c8acebaea7c103:0xb4e4a90c507e03a2!8m2!3d52.7092108!4d4.9585823!9m1!1b1!16s%2Fg%2F11c3k693v6?authuser=0&hl=en&entry=ttu")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[role=tab][aria-label*=Reviews]'))).click()
reviews = wait_for_value_to_stop_changing(get_reviews)

for i in range(9):
    print(f"Review {i + 1}")
    print(reviews[i].text)
```